# 3way switch not working properly

Tags: electrical

I have a 3 way switch, if I turn it on in the kitchen and off in the dining room all is fine, now if my someone else turns it on in kitchen nothing happens, you turn it on in the dining room and off at the kitchen all's good, but to turn it on in the dining room nothing, help thanks

Comment: Its wired wrong. Is the switch newly installed?

Comment: Has something changed, or was it always like this?

Comment: Something is wired wrong. Pull out the switches and post a picture of the wires going to each one.

Comment: Can you post clear photos of the wiring in both switch boxes? When was the switch installed, and when did this behavior appear?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter if new or old but it sounds like one switch is wired correctly the other has a traveler and common reversed (quite common DIY mistake). The one plus here is by swapping one of the travelers and common it won't cause any hazards and may fix your problem. The common on the switch is usually a black screw the travelers are brass. Do this with the circuit breaker off and give it a try, if it only changed the switch position try the other side as the first try just swapped travelers the second try should do the trick.

Comment: It worked properly for the last 18 years, when the house was remodeled, elec was was done by a licensed electrician

Comment: Licensed or not 1 of the switches is miswired, the electrician only verified 1 location.